# React Native Module Cannot Be Null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native (0.44.0) is giving me the error of the native module cannot be null, It seems like it is referring to the urban airship library not being found. Any thoughts?

[My dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P60O8.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhzJy.jpg)

Comment: You should include the *dependencies* and *errors* as text and not as images

Comment: Did you follow the full installation instructions for Urban Airships integration? https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/react-native/#ios

Comment: @gtfargo Yep. Well, I took over development from some other devs. I then signed up and got my apple certificate and put the secret ids and whatnot in the required files.

Comment: did you ever fix this? i have the same issue